# Basic PHP/MySQL math example

Tags: php, mysql, math

I have a PHP form that grabs user-entered data and then posts it to a MySQL database.  I'd like to know, how I can take the mathematical difference between two fields and post it to a third field in the database?

For example, I'd like to subtract **"travel_costs"** from **"show_1_price"** and write the difference to the **"total_cost"** variable. What's the best way to do this?  Thanks so much.

Comment: what are the data types of the variables?  int or decimal?  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: INT.  Yes I've tried doing something like "$total_cost = $show_1_price - $travel_costs;" in my insert.php file but I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You can lately process a select query: SELECT show_1_price - travel_costs AS pricediff FROM my_table; and then grab value in php and again do an insert query...

Comment: Why would you do a SELECT when inserting rows in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple to do on the PHP side of things how about

```
query=sprintf("INSERT INTO table VALUES(%d, %d, %d)", travel_costs,
show_1_price, show_1_price - travel_cost);
```

Generally though it is bad form to store a value in a database that can be calculated from other values. The reason being that you may never ever access this value again yet you are using storage for it. CPU cycles are much more abundant today so calculate the value when need. This is not a golden rule though - there are times when it could be more efficient to store the calculated value - although this is not usually the case.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. So are you saying that it's better to calculate the field dynamically with a formula of some sort instead of writing an actual value to the database? Sorry, trying to understand

Comment: @ISOcrates Exactly - because the value can be calculated from existing columns you can calculate it when you need it. eg SELECT travel_costs, show_1_price, show_1_price - travel_cost AS total_cost FROM my_table;

Comment: Here is a paste of exactly what I'm working with: http://pastie.org/3099546. What can I add to insert.php to get it to post the difference of the entered data in "show_1_price" and "travel_costs" to the "total_costs" field in the database?  I know it's not the most efficient way of doing things but it'll work for my current needs.

Comment: Ok well you should be able to extend that easily - just add the another which is the subtraction of the two. But IMHO you are going to get hacked if you are passing user provided values to the database like this.

Comment: Do I do something like this?
`$travel=$_POST['travel_costs'];`
`$query="update bookings set total_cost=show_1_price+$travel where id=13";` Also, how would you suggest handling the user information?